# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean... expected single matching bean but found 12

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, generics, dao

I'm creating a program which has around 12 DAO's and Services so far. The DAO's and Services are primarily the same, so I built a generic DAO and Service which is extended by the 12 DAO's and Services I made so they can all have access to save, update, delete and findById. Everything was working perfectly whenever I used just 1 class for testing (`RegularUser`) but as soon as I switched all the classes over to extending the generic DAO and Service, I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'genericServiceImpl' defined in file [C:\Users\Contronym\workspace\Glimps App\target\classes\com\glimpsmedia\app\generic\service\GenericServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type [com.glimpsmedia.app.generic.dao.GenericDao] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 12: businessCategoryDaoImpl,businessUserDaoImpl,campaignCategoryDaoImpl,campaignDaoImpl,competitorDaoImpl,followDaoImpl,friendDaoImpl,giveawayDaoImpl,glimpsDaoImpl,regularUserDaoImpl,userCategoryDaoImpl,viewDaoImpl; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.glimpsmedia.app.generic.dao.GenericDao] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 12: businessCategoryDaoImpl,businessUserDaoImpl,campaignCategoryDaoImpl,campaignDaoImpl,competitorDaoImpl,followDaoImpl,friendDaoImpl,giveawayDaoImpl,glimpsDaoImpl,regularUserDaoImpl,userCategoryDaoImpl,viewDaoImpl
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.glimpsmedia.app.main.App.main(App.java:14)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.glimpsmedia.app.generic.dao.GenericDao] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 12: businessCategoryDaoImpl,businessUserDaoImpl,campaignCategoryDaoImpl,campaignDaoImpl,competitorDaoImpl,followDaoImpl,friendDaoImpl,giveawayDaoImpl,glimpsDaoImpl,regularUserDaoImpl,userCategoryDaoImpl,viewDaoImpl
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveNotUnique(DependencyDescriptor.java:172)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1059)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:834)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
    ... 15 more
```

My generic DAO:

```
public class GenericDaoImpl<T> implements GenericDao<T> {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private final Class<T> type;

    public GenericDaoImpl(final Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public void save(final T obj) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(obj);
            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if(tx != null)
                tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }

    }

    public void update(final T obj) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            session.update(obj);
            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if(tx != null)
                tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }

    }

    public void delete(final T obj) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            session.delete(obj);
            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if(tx != null)
                tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }

    }

    public T findById(final long id) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        T obj = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            obj = session.get(type, id);
            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if(tx != null)
                tx.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }

        return obj;
    }

}
```

My generic service:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class GenericServiceImpl<T> implements GenericService<T> {

    private GenericDao<T> dao;

    @Autowired
    public GenericServiceImpl(GenericDao<T> dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    public void save(T obj) {
        dao.save(obj);
    }

    public void update(T obj) {
        dao.update(obj);
    }

    public void delete(T obj) {
        dao.delete(obj);
    }

    public T findById(long id) {
        return dao.findById(id);
    }

}
```

Also, here's an example of one of the DAO's. They're all the same except for the class name(there's 12 of them):

```
@Repository("regularUserDaoImpl")
public class RegularUserDaoImpl extends GenericDaoImpl<RegularUser> 
    implements RegularUserDao {

    public RegularUserDaoImpl() {
        super(RegularUser.class);
    }

}
```

And an example of a service(again, there's 12 of these, one for each DAO):

```
@Service("regularUserServiceImpl")
@Transactional
public class RegularUserServiceImpl extends GenericServiceImpl<RegularUser> 
    implements RegularUserService {

    public RegularUserServiceImpl(GenericDao<RegularUser> dao) {
        super(dao);
    }

}
```

I tried doing some research on this, and saw something regarding an `@Qualifier` tag, but I have no idea how I'd implement it here since the `@Autowired` tag in the generic classes have 12 different options to choose from, so I don't know what to put into `@Qualifier` or how to make `@Qualifier` dynamic.

Comment: https://www.jayway.com/2013/11/03/spring-and-autowiring-of-generic-types/ is this what you're looking for?

Comment: @Compass Definitely helpful in explaining why it doesn't work, but it doesn't solve my issue since I also have a generic `Service` where the `Dao` is put. I believe my implementation is wrong. Possibly need to put the `Dao` in the non-generic `DaoImpl` classes and then pass it to the generic service? I'll try that and see if it works.

Comment: @Compass unable to figure it out... Any suggestions?

Comment: If you can have 12 generic services you are imho doing things wrong. Services are about use cases not about save/update/deletes. Also instead of using plain hibernate I suggest using Spring Data JPA which basically  means you can ditch your 12 implementations and only leave 12 interfaces. Your services add nothing only another layer of complexity (they are only passing things to the repository anyway).

Comment: @M.Deinum I saw a few posts saying calling the methods in the DAO directly is bad practice? Is this actually bad practice? Should I call the DAO's save, update, delete, and findById directly if I want to do simply operations on the database, then implement service methods for business logic / more complicated database interactions?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `@Service` annotation from `GenericServiceImpl`, it's telling Spring to create a generic service with a generic DAO, which is probably not what you want. Also a suggestion: make `GenericDaoImpl` and `GenericServiceImpl` abstract, so no one tries to instantiate them.
And there will be no need in `@Qualifier` or `@Primary`.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up fixing it. There's no need for `@Qualifier` in Spring 4.0 and onward. I ended up adding the `@Primary` tag to one of my DAO's. Fixed the problem and everything works perfectly now. Spring gets confused for some reason unless you have `@Primary` above one of the DAO's.

Comment: That's because you have 12 different beans that implement `GenericDao`; if you inject `GenericDao`, then Spring does not know which one of the 12 you want to have injected. With `@Primary` you indicate the one that you want to have injected.

Comment: @Jesper I put the @Primary above the `RegularUserDaoImpl` but whenever I try to instantiate a `BusinessUserDaoImpl` or any other DAO/service, it uses the right ones. It doesn't inject a `RegularUserDao` unless I try to instantiate a `RegularUserDao`. What's the reason for that?

Comment: Have a look at Roman's answer, he's on the right track. If you intended for `GenericServiceImpl` to be a superclass for specific service implementations, then you should not put a `@Service` annotation on `GenericServiceImpl`, because then Spring will instantiate it directly. The `@Service` annotation should only be on the specific subclasses. It's also a good idea to make `GenericServiceImpl` and `GenericDaoImpl` `abstract` - they're only meant to be used as superclasses, and not to be instantiated by themselves.

Comment: @Jesper I removed the @Service from the `GenericServiceImpl` and I made both the `GenericServiceImpl` and `GenericDaoImpl` abstract. I still receive the same issue regarding Spring not knowing which subclass to inject.